# Python: sampling subsets with controlled repetitions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I have N, M, K and P, and I need to find K subsets of [N] (ie. all the integers in the range [1, N]) where each subset is the size of M. P is in the range [0, 1] and is the upper bound of the intersection ration between any two subsets can be (ie. for P = 0 all subsets are disjoint, for P = 0.5 any two subsets can share **up to** half of their elemets etc.

For instance with P = 0 we can simply use numpy.random.choice(B, (K, M) false)

Possible relaxations:

- N, M and K not overly large - N < 1000, M,K << N
- M = N / K

As far as I can see there's no way to achieve this without resampling and evaluating each subset against all other subsets iteratively but such a solution will be too inefficient and crude.

**example for such naive implementation**

```
def getSubsets(N,M,K, P):
    subsets = []
    for k in range(K):
        passed = 0
        subset = np.random.choice(N, M, False)

        while(passed < k):
            subset = np.random.choice(N, M, False)

            for x in subsets:
                intersection_size = np.sum([1 if np.nonzero(x == ele)[0].size > 0 else 0 for ele in subset])
                if intersection_size / M <= P:
                    passed += 1

        subsets.append(subset)

    return subsets
```

preferably the solution will be 3.x compatible.

Comment: I've added my naive implementation.

Comment: How large can N be?  Can you set an upper bound?

Comment: Added. N < 1000, M and K much smaller than N (< 100)